# Create insert record dynamically by changing pk of existing record for passed in table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pass a table name and schema into a procedure, and have it generate insert, update and delete statements for the particular table.  This is part of an automated testing solution (in a development environment) in which I need to test some change data capture.  I want to make this dynamic as it is going to be need to be done for lots of different tables over a long period of time, and I need to call it via a REST request through ORDS, so don't want to have to make an endpoint for every table.

Update and delete are fairly easy, however I am struggling with the insert statement.  Some of the tables being passed in have hundreds of columns with various constraints, fks etc. so I think it makes sense to just manipulate an existing record by changing only the primary key.  I need to be able to modify the primary key to a new value known to me beforehand (e.g. '-1').

Ideally I would create a dynamic `rowtype`, and `select into where rownum = 1`, then loop round the primary keys found from `all_constraints`, and update the `rowtype.pk` with my new value, before inserting this into the table.  Essentially the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972743/inserting-from-a-select-but-changing-one-column) but without knowing the table in advance.

e.g. rough idea

```
PROCEDURE manipulate_records(p_owner in varchar2, p_table in varchar2)
IS
   cursor c_pk is
      select column_name
        from all_cons_columns
       where owner = p_owner
         and constraint_name in (select constraint_name
                                   from all_constraints
                                  where table_name = p_table
                                    and constraint_type = 'P');

   l_row  tbl_passed_in%ROWTYPE --(I know this isn't possible but ideally)

BEGIN
   -- dynamic sql or refcursor to collect a record
   select * into tbl_passed_in from tablename where rownum = 1;

   -- now loop through pks and reassign their values to my known value
   for i in c_pk loop
   ...if matches then reassign;
   ...
   end loop;

   -- now insert the record into the table passed in
END manipulate_records;
```

I have searched around but haven't found any examples which fit this exact use case, where an unknown column needs to be modified and insert into a table.

Comment: Have you considered [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73) ?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how that helps me in this case.  What in particular were you thinking?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? (If 18c+, a polymorphic table function may be helpful.) Since you're looping through primary keys columns, I assume that means you have natural keys, where each column could also be a foreign key. In that case a -1 wouldn't work in those columns.

Comment: 19c.  I was playing around with polymorphic functions yesterday trying to get a describe table type but wasn't giving me exactly what I wanted.  I'll have another look.  Re. natural keys, I don't think that will be an issue with the datasets we are looking at, but definitely something to be aware of, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex your procedure is, you might be able to store it as a template in a CLOB.  Then pull it in, replace table and owner, then compile it.

```
    DECLARE
    prc_Template        VARCHAR2(4000);
    vc_Owner            VARCHAR2(0008);
    vc_Table            VARCHAR2(0008);
BEGIN
    vc_Table := 'DUAL';
    vc_Owner := 'SYS';
    
    -- Pull code into prc_Template from CLOB, but this demonstrates the concept
    prc_Template := 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xyz AS r_Dual    <Owner>.<Table>%ROWTYPE; BEGIN NULL; END;';
    prc_Template := REPLACE(prc_Template,'<Owner>',vc_Owner);
    prc_Template := REPLACE(prc_Template,'<Table>',vc_Table);
    -- Create the procedure
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE prc_Template;
END;
```

Then you have the appropriate ROWTYPE available:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xyz AS r_Dual SYS.DUAL%ROWTYPE; BEGIN NULL; END;
```

But you can't create the procedure and run it in the same code block.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It wouldn't work for my use case due to how I am calling the procedure but a may help someone else.